# Grep in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a subdirectory called `Liste` and I have `texte` files inside, I want to find a text (a telephone number inside):

```
read $number
while ! grep -l $number * Liste; do
    echo"Le fichier n'existe pas"
    read $number
done
grep -l  $number * Liste
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks.

I made a mistake here's my code, and it shows me 2 time the ./Liste/"name"

Comment: You can use: `grep -H "$number" Liste/*`

Comment: When you run the `grep` command after the loop, you repeat what worked inside the loop, so you get the output twice.  It is doing what you asked it to do; you just need to figure out what you want it to do.  For my money, drop the second `grep` command.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the argument to `read` is a variable *name*, not its value.  In other words, drop the dollar sign.

```
read number
while ! grep -iq "$number" Liste/*; do
     echo "Le numero n'existe pas"
     read number
done
echo " Le numero existe"
```

Note also how to quote properly, and how to refer to all the files in the directory `Liste`.  Finally, the `-q` option suppresses the normal output from `grep` (it would print every match -- every line in every file in the directory if you entered something like `.`!) Finally, notice also that the space after `echo` is mandatory.

Update: If you want to list the file names with matches without the leading directory name, `cd` into the directory first.

```
cd Liste
read number
while ! grep -il "$number" *; do
    echo "Le numéro n'existe pas"
    read number
done
echo "Le numéro existe"
```

(I added the `-l` option on the assumption that you *only* want the file name; but if you don't, just remove it.)

Comment: thank you but if i use cd, when i make a while to restart the whole code, will I have an error ?

Comment: I don't see why you would.  The `cd` only affects the script, not its parent process. When the script exits, you are back in the parent shell. (This is presuming that you store the commands in a script file, of course.  If you put them in a shell function, that would be different.  But then just wrap the function with parentheses, like `cherche () { ( cd Liste; read number; while ! grep -i "$number" *; do echo "Le numéro n'existe pas"; read number; done; echo "Le numéro existe" ) ; }` -- the parentheses create a subshell.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
grep "$number" ./Liste/* >/dev/null && echo "Le numero existe" || echo "Le fichier n'existe pas"
```

Or if you want to output the name of the file that matches, use the `l` option:

```
grep -l "$number" ./Liste/*
```

Based on your comment, use:

```
grep -l "$number" Liste/* | xargs basename
```

Comment: I just want to show the name of the file without ./Liste/name.. and here it shows it 2 times, first with ./Liste/name/number_putted_In then with ./Liste/name/

Comment: see the last part of the answer